# Rails, squeel - loop inside 'where'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, squeel

I want to use some sort of loop or iterator inside where statement like

```
Product.where{ array.each do |e|
  (id >= e[0]) & (id <= e[1])
end }
```

Is something like this possible?

In reality query is much more complicated, and I don't want to post whole architecture here.

Comment: No. It is however possible to generate a query string based on the arrays before, and insert them into the where statement

Comment: That's sat... Well, let's use ol' good string query...

Comment: Will array always contain 2 values?

Comment: @eabraham Yes they will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.where('id >= ? AND id <= ?',array[0],array[1])
```

Comment: Well, thanks, I figured out something like this, but I wanted squeel solution. Whatever, I accept your answer to close this question.